# Choice of a model for Bayesian Change Point Detection

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc, change-point

I am getting my hands dirty with Probabilistic Programming using Bayesian approach to change-point detection. I read a number of tutorials provided with PyMC and reading the book by Cameron Davidson-Pilon "Bayesian Methods for Hackers". My main question is about the choice of the model for change-point detection. My secondary question relates to PyMC usage.

The data has been synthetically generated: 1000 data points with $\mu_1=3.0, \sigma_1=2.0$ and another 1000 data points with $\mu_2=2.0, \sigma_2=1.0$. This makes a single time-series data of 2000 data points with a single change-point in the middle.

I am attempting to answer the following two questions:

1. Where is the change-point?
2. What are the posteriors for the model parameters $\mu_1, \mu_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2$?

The change-point has been modeled using Discrete Uniform distribution:
$\tau \sim \text{Uniform}(0,2000)$

The four parameters I am interested in are modeled using the Exponential distribution:

$\mu_1 \sim \text{Exp}(\alpha)$

$\mu_2 \sim \text{Exp}(\alpha)$

$\sigma_1 \sim \text{Exp}(\beta)$

$\sigma_2 \sim \text{Exp}(\beta)$

where the hyper-priors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were set to $\frac{1}{\hat\mu}$ and $\frac{1}{\hat\sigma}$. The $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ are computed from the 2000 data points.

Finally the observed data is modeled using the Normal distribution: $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$

Question: Is this model reasonable for this data and the task?

---

The Python code using PyMC:

Question: How to use the switch method correctly when there are more than one variable to select from?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc3 as pm

from pymc3 import DiscreteUniform, Normal, switch, traceplot

mu1_true = 3.0
mu2_true = 5.0
sigma1_true = 2.0
sigma2_true = 1.0

n1 = 1000
n2 = 1000
n = n1 + n2

data1 = np.random.normal(mu1_true,sigma1_true,n1)
data2 = np.random.normal(mu2_true,sigma2_true,n2)
data = np.concatenate((data1,data2),axis=0)
t = np.arange(0,n)

#plt.plot(t,data)
#plt.show()

# hyper prior
alpha = 1.0/np.mean(data)
beta = 1.0/np.std(data)

model = pm.Model()

with model:
    switchpoint = DiscreteUniform("switchpoint", lower=0, upper=n)
    mu_1 = pm.Exponential("mu_1", alpha)
    mu_2 = pm.Exponential("mu_2", alpha)
    sd_1 = pm.Exponential("sd_1", beta)
    sd_2 = pm.Exponential("sd_2", beta)
    mu = switch( switchpoint >= t, mu_1, mu_2 )
    sd = switch( switchpoint >= t, sd_1, sd_2 )
    X = Normal('x',mu=mu,sd=sd,observed=data)

with model:
    step1 = pm.NUTS( [mu_1, mu_2, sd_1, sd_2] )
    step2 = pm.Metropolis( [switchpoint] )
    trace = pm.sample( 10000, step=[step1,step2] )

traceplot(trace,varnames=['switchpoint','mu_1','mu_2', 'sd_1', 'sd_2'])
plt.show()
```

The posteriors for the parameters of interest are clearly very close to the true values and not overlapping. The change-point position is inferred pretty accurately as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all looks very reasonable to me. There's a bit of autocorrelation in the switchpoint posterior but I think with more samples it shouldn't be a concern. Then you might also want to discard the first 100 or so samples as burn-in. Other than that you're off to a great start!

Comment: What does it indicate if I observe autocorrelation in a posterior? Where to look at to fix it or lower the effect? And finally, what is "burn-in", what is it used for?

Comment: Burn-in means discarding the first couple of samples, you can see very early on the trace walks around until it hits the actual posterior. In general, these are fairly basic questions. I recommend checking out http://camdavidsonpilon.github.io/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/ and/or Kruschke's puppy book.

Comment: I've also written about this in my blog: http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2015/11/10/mcmc-sampling/