# Priors as Controls : Bayesian Regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, stan

I have a general question about Bayesian Regression Modeling and how a prior might be used as a means to control for (close to) simultaneous events. I often face a situation where I have a time series of sales and am looking to estimate the impact of an event (on the trend and level). This would be a candidate for an interrupted time series model - encoding periods post the event as 1 and 0 prior. The problem is that there are often other events that have not happened before, in close proximity time wise to the event of interest - maybe at the same time for all or part of the same time as the event of interest.

If I am willing to use ‘side information’ (maybe from subject matter experts or analysis in another region) …can I use a strong informative prior to ‘control’ for these other events and estimate the one I care most about?

Comment: It would be possible provided highly informative prior, I’m not a Bayesian expert, but see [here](http://www.econ.cam.ac.uk/people-files/emeritus/mhp1/fp18/PS_high_collinearity_6_October_2018.pdf). I would search for “multi colinearity and Bayesian regression” which is what you have.

Comment: I am not so sure but I have a feeling that it might be better if you could write down the model that you are using along with the parameters that you are focusing on.

Comment: I'm not sure what your idea with the priors is, but from your problem description I wonder if [change-point models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/207438) would be right for.